# selecting multiple times from two tables to get two different result

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I am using apex application building to create a report.

Table

**staff**

```
id    name

201   john
302   sarah
787   bob
```

**product**

```
product_editor_id     product_name

201                   car
307                   shoe
728                   airbag
```

as you can see in the staff table I have staff details and in the product I have the staff id to show the staff that created it.

in my report I have selected everything from the staff table, but you see where I have staff `id` i don't want to show the `id` but instead their name

I have rewritten a query for this. The reason why I am asking this question is that in the previous query I had something like this

```
select * from staff Inner join
company_car ON
staff.staff_car_id=company_car.vehicle_id_staffid
```

if that query doesn't make sense. Basically I did this to only display staff that has a company car and the vehicle_id_staffid is the same as the staff id.

anyways on top for that query I need to add my new query to it which is

```
select distinct name from staff
left join product on 
staff.id=product.product_editor_id
```

**I tried**

```
select * from staff Inner join
company_car ON
staff.staff_car_id=company_car.vehicle_id_staffid
UNION
select distinct name from staff
left join product on 
staff.id=product.product_editor_id
```

but apex said `ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns`

I want the result from it to be different. The first query should have any problem with the second query because they are but doing their own thing.

Comment: are the 2 queries actually related, or do they serve different purposes? If different then you should simply keep the two separate and not introduce a UNION. The reason you get the error is because the columns returned by the 1st query are different to the 2nd - this can be easily fixed but then the result set may not make much sense.

Comment: @nickebbitt thats a great idea but the thing is in apex application builder when you go on the `Edit Region` you only have one `source` to write the query and in the source. the report will render with whatever you choose to select from your query. That is issue. if it wasnt this way i would have done as you just said

Comment: @nickebbitt is correct though. You're trying to do something which is not possible. When you union queries they require the same set of columns and not 4 from query 1 and 3 from query 2. What is the goal: show all staff info for staff which have a company car and/or are a product editor?

Comment: @Tom i `TRIED` union because I am trying to show the staff name instead of their `id`. so by using union i thought if it checks the staff table and the `id` matches the one in the `product` table then it will return `name` instead. Hope that makes sense

Comment: @uykenpachi I mean no offense, but this is some basic sql knowledge. We can of course provide the answer but I strongly suggest that you pick up a book or course or some sort of good reading material to learn some more about this. The first step to writing a query that gets what you want is to simply consider: what do i have, what do i need, and what do i have at my disposal. Similarly when asking your question you should keep this in mind, since your question is really unclear! You trying to perform a union for a mysterious reason confounds the problem only further. Again, no offense meant.

Comment: Having said that, I'm still unclear on your goal: you want to show staff records (name, and/or any other column from staff). Only staff with a company car. And only staff who are product editors. ?

Comment: @Tom You are right, it is clearly my stupidity with this issue. All i needed to do was a simple inline select statement. Sorry to waste anyone times and thanks all for your help

Comment: No problem - I wouldn't call it stupidity, that's too derogatory. Asking questions is not stupid, not knowing is not stupid. If you want to learn and take some advice then that is not stupid. Your issue got resolved by reflecting on it - that's good.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way would be to create original report with staff_id in it.So 
create new report as new page or as region on the page.
-something like :

```
Select * from company_car
```

So you get report that will have staff_id as one of the columns.Then you edit page properties and go to report.

[image]

Select **report attributes** and from the list of columns you have in the report you chose staff_id column **edit** ( pencil icon on the left).

Go to display as and select **'Display as Text based on LOV dont save state'**

List of value will appear. Go to list of values section

and type :

```
select id r, name d from staff;
```

or

```
select id r, name||' '||surname d from staff;
```

in here you need to link staff_id with name and their surname which will be displaying on the report instead of meaningless id. Alternatively you can create static LOV and use it to populate this column or you can try to build JOIN statement.

Comment: it is a report/form. so i dont have the option to edit that particularly field/column unfortunately

Comment: I am confused. Are you trying to get data from DB or insert data? Usually element on the page is either form or report. Please bear in mind that you have more than one form or report per page...